# org mode setup problem when trying to use capture

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I was trying to use the capture as is explained in org-manual p 74. 
This is the .emacs file for org mode.

```
(require 'org-install)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(setq org-log-done t)

(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "~/notes.org")) <-- error
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
```

But I get this error. What might be wrong?

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: org-directory
```

#### ADDED

After Dave's answer, I modified the code, and it seems to work fine. But the other problem that I found was C-c c gives me this error.

```
Symbol's function definition is void : org-capture
```

Comment: What's the output of `M-x org-version`?

Comment: @Dave : M-x org-version gives me [no match].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, make sure you're using org-mode 6.36 or later. (Earlier versions use remember.el which has a different setup.)

You're using a symbol that's not defined, `org-directory`.
Try using:

```
(setq org-default-notes-file (expand-file-name "~/notes.org"))
```

---

**Followup**:
To load a recent org-mode package:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/my/home/emacs.d/org-7.01h/lisp")
(require 'org-install)
(require 'org) ;; maybe this line is redundant
```

Note that as packaged, the org-mode lisp files are in the lisp sub-directory.

Comment: How do I check the version of org mode? I just download the Aqumacs on my Mac.

Comment: @proseek, this (http://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org.el) from the Aquamacs source shows that the Aquamacs org-mode version is 6.33x. You'll have to download/install a more recent org-mode release to get org-capture.

Comment: I installed the newest org mode as is  written in the manual (add the installed directory to exec-path), but it seems that the old version of org-mode seems to run.

Comment: @proseek, exec-path? do you mean load-path? The .emacs lines that I added to my answer loaded the most recent org-mode in my Aquamacs.

Comment: Debian Squeeze defaults to org-mode 6.33, so downloading the newer .deb file from the org-mode website solved this for me.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been answered, but I would like to leave a more thorough answer for those people who haven't been successful.  I just went through the motions and I am going to make a list of each step below.

1. http://orgmode.org/ and download tar.gz (at time of download it was Stable version 7.9.2 (sept. 2012)
2. untar (tar -zxvf nameoffile.tar.gz OR just double click the file)
3. edit the local.mk file to put files where you want them. I have a folder in my user directory called Scripts where I keep things orderly based on scripting language. I decided to keep my emacs stuff there too. Inside the scripts folder is a folder called "emacs". As a prefix, I used "Scripts", but I could have made the Prefix "/Users/Username/Scripts/emacs". I just had to make sure that the other directories started with "$(prefix)/emacs"—HINT: check the infodir.

   > ```
   > # Name of your emacs binary
   > EMACS = emacs
   > ```
   >
   > # Where local software is found
   >       prefix    = /Users/Username/Scripts
   >   
   >       # Where local lisp files go.
   >       lispdir= $(prefix)/emacs/lisp/org
   >   
   >       # Where local data files go.
   >       datadir = $(prefix)/emacs/etc/org
   >   
   >       # Where info files go.
   >       infodir = $(prefix)/emacs/info
4. Edit your .emacs file and paste in there two new paths (if not already there). The first one is for the lisp folder for any .el files you may have and the second one is there because I contained the org files in an org folder, which is a subfolder of lisp. Unfortunately, the "load-path" is not smart enough to detect subfolders, therefore you must set each folder explicitly.

   - (setq load-path (cons "~/Scripts/emacs/lisp" load-path))
   - (setq load-path (cons "~/Scripts/emacs/lisp/org" load-path))
5. Check version in Aquamacs or Emacs with M-x org-version (meta key + x and type "org-version")

HINT:

- nano ~/.emacs
- open -a Textedit ~/.emacs